# Using a single nginx for different projects

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, microservices

I have the following setup:

- web1: django application
- web2: flask application
- nginx: web frontend to serve web1 and web2

web1 and web2 are themselves complex projects, with several services (db, redis, ...).

Everything is managed with docker / docker-compose.

What annoys me of my current setup is that the nginx project needs to be setup specifically to serve the services behind it. This means, there is a tight coupling between the nginx project and the web1 / web2 projects. For example:

- static assets from web1 / web2 must be copied to the nginx project, and redeployed, each time that I need to re-collect static assets.
- the config of the enabled sites is done in the nginx project, but it is acually more related to the web1 / web2 projects
- certificates are part of the nginx project, but again those are more related to the respective projects

Originially I was having an `nginx` service in each of the projects, but once I decided to run all the services in the same machine, conflicts appeared. Besides, it seems wasteful to run several nginx instances in a single machine.

How are people solving these kind of issues? Do you have links to ideas on how to structure an nginx project as frontend to several projects?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what you mean by the nginx project ?  Do you mean under sites-enabled you have a web1.conf and a web2.conf ?  What I would interpret as the "application" would be path the conf points to under the relevant location and server block.  It's just not too clear what you mean by copying static assets to an nginx project and redeploying.  By redeploy do you mean a `systemctl restart` ?

Comment: @hmedia1the nginx project is a separate git project, with a deploy process (gitlab / docker / ansible). It is in charge of relaying requests to the oher services, which are deployed using a CI pipeline in their respective repositories. By copying assets I mean really running `cp web1/collected_assets nginx/static`. By redeploying I mean re-running the CI pipeline for the nginx project.